# Modifying boot order through MBR?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-10, boot, mbr

So I'm trying to modify the boot order on my machine. It seems it could be done through modifying the MBR(I think, not sure), and I haven't been able to find any good resource on how to achieve this.

Quick summary of what I'm trying to do: When we go to the BIOS Menu we're able to change the order of where the computer boot from. I have two drives one with Windows 10 and the other with Ubuntu installed. I want to do what the BIOS do, through the command prompt/terminal. Basically dd the right boot order into the right place in memory, so when I reboot the computer it will boot the right OS.

I've found a couple of good resources but I haven't really found anything to actually achieve what I'm trying to do. [This page](http://www.dewassoc.com/kbase/hard_drives/master_boot_record.htm) breaks down what the MBR looks like and what it does. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21647752/how-to-read-the-mbr-master-boot-record-in-c/21647848#21647848) shows me how to open up the MBR through the terminal.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on how to modify the boot order, and with what method? Or am I not even going in the right direction at all.

Comment: *"Modifying boot order through MBR?"* -- Not possible.

Answer (score 0):

What the BIOS does *isn't* editing the MBR; it's editing the **[internal NVRAM data](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonvolatile_BIOS_memory)**.

*(Think about it for a moment. You have two disks and **each has its own MBR**, so there must be something else telling the system which MBR is the primary one.)*

As for editing it through the command line:

- If by "BIOS" you actually meant UEFI, and if your Linux actually boots in EFI mode (rather than "CSM"/"BIOS"/"compatibility"/"legacy" mode), then the boot order is accessible via "EFI variables", e.g. using the **`efibootmgr`** tool. On Windows, `bcdedit /default` or EasyUEFI can do the same.

  *(As a side note, UEFI systems usually prefer GPT for storing partition information; not MBR.)*
- If all you have is a regular PC BIOS, you usually *cannot* access the boot order through the OS *at all* – you have to use the BIOS menu. (The same if it's an UEFI system configured to boot in "legacy" mode.)

Comment: I have both of the OS in Legacy mode. So does this mean I have reinstall everything in EFI mode? So the best way is to just use the efinbootmgr on Linux and bcdedit on Windows? Is there a way for me to use dd on the terminal to change the boot order in memory in ubuntu and do the same thing with cygwin on Windows?

So I tried using bcdedit on windows and modifying the grub and updating the grub.cfg to modify the boot order before. But what I get from it is that it would just bounce back and forth from the two. Windows wants to boot Ubuntu and Ubuntu wants to boot Windows.